# I have a B1-B2 Visa expiring Oct 2019 but will start using ESTA from now on. When should I apply for ESTA?

Tags: esta, b1-b2-visas

I have a B1-B2 visa (on my Venezuelan passport) that will expire Oct 12, 2019.

I will not renew that visa and will start using ESTA from now on (I am citizen of Spain also). My question is: When should I apply for ESTA? Before or after my B1-B2 visa expires?

I am traveling this week to the United States and I will travel again in September. 
Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Do you plan to travel to the US on you Spanish passport?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use your existing B1/B2 visa when it's still valid in September when you will visit? A visitor visa gives you a longer stay (usually 6 months instead of 90 days for VWP) and more options (e.g. you can change status).

Comment: Thank you! I can travel with my Venezuelan passport (which has the B1-B2 visa) in September. I was just asking to see when I should apply for the Esta. Before or just after my Visa expires?

Comment: Don't apply for ESTA until you need it.  If you can travel on the B1/B2, then use that, and next time you travel _after_ the visa expires, then apply for the Esta